# How to use Vee-Validate's setFieldValue with nested objects?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vee-validate

###### I'm using Vue 3 and [`vee-validate@4`](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4)

I want to use the [`setFieldValue`](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-form#composable-api) method to set `branding.name`'s value but it seems that I can't do that.

The method uses [Typescript's `keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) to validate the parameter.

```js
const { setFieldValue } = useForm({
  validationSchema: Yup.object({
    branding: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string().required(),
    })
  )}
)}

// Examples:
setFieldValue('branding.name', null)  // Not Working

// I can use only the "first item"
setFieldValue('branding', null)  // It makes sense but doesn't work (because `branding` is an object and not a field)
```

```html
<!-- This is a custom component -->
<InputField id="branding.name" />
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same question. It turns out it is quite simple. Just nest as you would any js object.

```
setFieldValue({
  branding: {
    name: 'your typed value'
  }
})
```

Comment: I got it fixed casting the parameter to `any`.
You can find out more here: https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/discussions/3681#discussioncomment-2129278